# Change images with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, image

I want to change the image arrow when clicked, for the moment i have this http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qEMLxq ,   but when clicked changed the current image but dont hide-

```
 <a id="Boton1" class="button" onClick="showHide()" href="javascript:void"><center>
    Lípidos<br>
     <img src="http://sakapa.itmui.com/todo/www/img/flecha_abajo.png" width="24" height="13" alt=""/>
  </center></a>
```

Comment: my advice is use css classes in order to show/hide rather than trying to check for and change specific css properties

Comment: Can you show your showHide() function too please?

Comment: hi @BillBokeey in the codepen link is all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your image arrow doesn't have any ID.

You need to give an id such as

```
<img id="flecha_abajo" />
```

Then in your function JavaScript showHide() you need to do

```
document.getElementById("flecha_abajo").style.display = none;
```

Comment: yeah, but when i clicked again dont change to the original arrow i want to made something like  if the down arrow is clicked change to the up arrow the if the up arrow is clicked change to the down arrow

Comment: @alsuelo, i would rather manipulate image src...like this: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MYqZdw

Comment: if it doesn't change back it is because you need to widthdraw the style.display none :) such as ....style.display = ""; Nervermind I think your code will download the picture again and again everytime the user click on the arrow.

Comment: Awesome now i understand... thank you so much i see what was te problem with the if